# How to set the cookieOptions option in treeview so that I can set the expires option of the cookie?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

When I looked at the **jquery.treeview.js** code then I saw this :

```
$.cookie(settings.cookieId, data.join(""), settings.cookieOptions );
```

Then I looked the code of the **jquery.cookie.js** file and I saw that there is the `expires` argument for the third argument "options".

So how to write correctly the **cookieOptions** in order to set the `expires` option ?

Answer (score 0):

cookieOptions is an object with defined params. So, you can use something like this:

```
$.cookie(name, value, {expires: days} );
```

Where days is an number of days. You can see it in documentation:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

So, your's `settings.cookieOptions = {expires: days}`

Comment: How can I write it inside the options of treeview ?

Comment: Can you give an exact link on treeview plugin you are using?

Comment: I dont remember the link : my coworker downloaded all the css and js files. My problem is that my tree menu collapsed after 3 clicks : on every click I must call the treeview method because I change submenus from database based on the clicked menu.

Comment: I think I found that treeview - [https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview), it calls like `$(element).treeview(options);`. So you can do something like `$(element).treeview({cookieId: 'your_cookie_id', cookieOptions: {expires: 7}})`

Comment: I tried but my tree menu is still collapsed after 3 clicks. Why is this behaviour ?

Comment: Can you show ann exact code of calling treeview? Also it may conflict with something, see browser console output or use debugger.